# Is there a way on how to get the last inserted id that has prefix?

Tags: java, mysql, database, prefix

I want to get the last inserted id but it has a prefix on it like for example "SIN0000001"
and when I enter this code it creates an error that says No value specified for parameter 1.

It should pop up a GUI which says

> Successfully recorded!

but it only saves the data directly to the database and outputs an error.

Succesfully recorded!

I've also used triggers in my database to have prefixes in my id.

These are my two tables.
[sales](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c47GN.png) and [sales_seq](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZLCfd.png)

```
    DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
    LocalDateTime now = LocalDateTime.now();
    String date = dtf.format(now);
    
    String amount_due = jTextField_amountDuePayment.getText();
    String cash = jTextField_cash.getText();
    String balance = jTextField_balance.getText();
    int lastid = 0;
    
    try {
        String sale_query = "INSERT INTO dnk_database.sales (`date`, `amount_due`, `cash`,  `balance`) VALUES (?,?,?,?);";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(sale_query, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        pst.setString(1, date);
        pst.setString(2, amount_due);
        pst.setString(3, cash);
        pst.setString(4, balance);
        pst.executeUpdate();
        
        ResultSet generatedKeyResult = pst.getGeneratedKeys();
        
        if(generatedKeyResult.next()){
            lastid = generatedKeyResult.getInt(1);
        }
        
        Sell sell = new Sell();
        int rows = sell.jTable_itemList.getRowCount();
        
        String product_query = "INSERT INTO dnk_database.product_sales (`sales_number`, `product_barcode`, `sell_price`,  `quantity`,  `total`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);";
        pst = con.prepareStatement(product_query);
        
        String product_barcode = "";
        String price = "";
        String qty = "";
        int total = 0;
        
        for(int i = 0; i < sell.jTable_itemList.getRowCount(); i++){
            product_barcode = (String)sell.jTable_itemList.getValueAt(i, 0);
            price = (String)sell.jTable_itemList.getValueAt(i, 2);
            qty = (String)sell.jTable_itemList.getValueAt(i, 3);
            total = (int)sell.jTable_itemList.getValueAt(i, 4);
            
            pst.setInt(1, lastid);
            pst.setString(2, product_barcode);
            pst.setString(3, price);
            pst.setString(4, qty);
            pst.setInt(5, total);
            pst.executeUpdate();
        }
        
        pst.addBatch();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Succesfully recorded!");
        
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Payment.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    
    
}
```

Comment: What is supposedly `null`?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer it output this error -> No value specified for parameter 1. which is I think is the variable `lastid`

Comment: print `lastid` to verify it

Comment: @XtremeBaumer is just the same as what is in my code. It's just different syntax

Comment: You think `lastid` is null. Have you verified it? - Also, it can't be null, as its an primitive `int` which is always at least `0` and never null. So find out what exactly is null and return with that information

Comment: `if(generatedKeyResult.next())` have you checked if that `if` is ever entered? I guess that you statement does not return any generated keys, which might be cause by your trigger creating or altering the value

Comment: @XtremeBaumer Im sorry with the confusion, it always return 0 instead if the code ends before `Sell sell = new Sell();` while in the database I've already entered 3 data items. So it should be `SIN0000003` and when I run the whole code it outputs an error No value specified for parameter 1

Comment: Please show table schema. Do you want the ID of the insert?

Comment: @AnchetaLaurentAntoineC What is Sell class?

Comment: @XtremeBaumer im thinking of that whole day around. im not really sure because the `sales` table has all the columns that needs to fulfill while the another table was for only the `sales_number`. Its just shakes my head

Comment: As Bohemian said, provide the table schema. Also could help to include the full stacktrace in the question

Comment: @DrishtiJain this is where you input the barcode of a certain item.product then quantity then when you click the button `Process` it will proceed to the `Payment` class which is the code above belong